# How to restrict deleting rows in TableView only to certain users?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, row, delete-row

My problem is as follows. I created an app that allows users to add posts to rows in TableViewController. It also lets them delete only their posts with `UITableViewCellEditingStyle` by checking if the current user has the same id as the id of the user who created the post. Unfortunately, this way of editing the cells also allows to try to delete others users posts. I would like to make that the delete button only appears when users swipe their posts. I attach [an image of the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6IW6.png) I have been talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

If you don't have a custom class for UITableViewCell:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    if owner[indexPath.row] == me {
        return .Delete
    }
    else {
        return .None
    }
 }
```

**Or** if you have a custom class for UITableViewCell then this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    if (tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! YourTableViewCell).owner == me {
        return .Delete
    }
    else {
        return .None
    }
}
```

Comment: what is me here?

Answer (score 0):

Simply do the check for matching user ids in the tableview's delegate `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath`, returning `UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None` if the user is invalid.

[Reference for editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:)

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but could you give me an example of how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this, remember to set the default editingStyle for cell

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return owner[indexPath.row] == me
    }
```